# What causes the Error: Naive Bayes Classifier (129): Naive Bayes Classification: Error: 'nresponse' is an empty string in Alteryx

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naivebayes, alteryx

I am try build a Naive Bayes Classifier in Alteryx and am attempting to pass through about 7,500 records however whenever I run the workflow I get the Error: Naive Bayes Classifier (129): Naive Bayes Classification: Error: 'nresponse' is an empty string. Whenever I decrease the number of records down to around 200 it runs the workflow just fine and does not throw this error. I would just like to now what is causing this and how to fix it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll get this if the field you're predicting has a null or empty value. To get around it, try filtering such values out of your dataset prior to running the Naive Bayes Classifier. (And if desired, retain the filtered records for further review.)